# How to bind a datatable inside an object to a datagrid in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a viewmodelclass, inside which a datatable is a part of another model class. I want to bind it to the datagrid in XAML. I have just started to learn MVVM. Any help would be appreciated.

My Model Class:

```
 public class AllResultsModel
  {
    private DataTable _allresultsgrid;

    private int _numberofrows;
    public DataTable AllResultsGrid
    {
        get { return _allresultsgrid; }
        set { _allresultsgrid = value; }
    }

    public int NumberOfRows
    {
        get { return _numberofrows; }
        set { _numberofrows = value; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
 private AllResultsModel _allresultstable;
 public AllResultsModel AllResultsTable
    {

        get { return _allresultstable; }
        set
        {
            _allresultstable = value;
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="results_grid" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AllResultsTable}" DisplayMemberPath="AllResultsGrid" ColumnWidth="100" RowHeight="30">
```

I want to bind the Allresultsgrid in Allresultsmodel to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind property same as we are accessing objects inside a class using [ClassName].[ObjectName]. Here you can achieve as mentioned below.

```
<DataGrid Name="results_grid" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AllResultsTable.AllResultsGrid}" DisplayMemberPath="AllResultsGrid" ColumnWidth="100" RowHeight="30">
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. Also, can you please let me know how multiple viewmodels can be bound to an xaml file?

Comment: you can assign only one ViewModel as datacontext but you can create instances of multiple view models and can access them in view. For more detail explanation you should raise a new question. this is a very interesting topic.

Comment: This is the link to my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248310/how-to-bind-multiple-viewmodels-to-a-single-xaml-file-in-mvvm-wpf